# Redirect to app from in-app browser on Android

Tags: android, inappbrowser

In the native Android app we are building we need to open a browser to our website to log the user in. When the login is succesful, the browser redirects back to the app by using our custom URL scheme (so something like this: `myapp://authenticate?token=abc123`).

This seemed to work just fine, but now we discovered that on some Android devices, the browser is not opened. Instead an in-app Chrome browser is opened, causing different behaviour. Because it is in-app, the redirect to our app using the custom URL scheme does in fact arrive in the app: the user is successfully logged in! But the problem is: the in-app browser window is still visible! The user now needs to manually close it.

I see two ways to fix this, but for both ways I have no clue if this is even possible.

1. Find a way to programmatically close the in-app browser window
2. Find a way to prevent the in-app browser to open in the first place (always open the full Chrome app).

If anyone can provide me with a clue on how to do any of these two things, it's very appreciated!

Also, we can't even reliably reproduce this issue. On some Android devices this happens and on some it doesn't. So if anyone has a clue what setting on Android influences the behaviour of opening an in-app browser, I would like to know that as well!

Answer (score 0):

i have read your question and i understand your point.

in that case you can use WebView for your website in popup window not open full browser, when user logged in successfully then just close the popup of your browser.

Please let me know it helps you or not.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. This is a solution, I agree. But we intend not to do that, because in a web view you don't have access to saved usernames/passwords. The benefit of the separate browser is that your username and password could be pre-filled if you logged in before.